# How to avoid my web services to crash when an email couldn't be sent, on Laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

I have a function I use to send all emails from the API (using Swiftmailer):

```
public static function send_email($page, $subject, $email, $email_data) {
    if (env('MAIL_USERNAME') && env('MAIL_PASSWORD')) {
        try {
            $site_url = url('/');
            Mail::queue($page, [
                'email_data' => $email_data,
                'site_url' => $site_url,
            ], function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {
                $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
            });
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Helper::get_error_message(123);
        }
        return Helper::get_message(105);
    }else {
        return Helper::get_error_message(123);
    }
}
```

Everything was working fine until the client moved his Mail Server to another provider (without any warning to us!!).

The configuration was right and some of emails continued to work well, while others stopped suddenly to work. This was due to the new provider's policy, which considered some emails as SPAM.

The problem is that when the new provider detects emails as SPAM, there is a ugly error on server side causing the web service to crash, and then the mobile app too..

This line is causing the issue:

```
$message->to($email)->subject($subject);
```

When the provider detects the email as spam, I can find this kind of error in Laravel logs:

```
[2018-02-06 14:14:47] local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.2.0 Spam message rejected " in /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383 Stack trace:
#0 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('550 5.2.0 Spam ...', Array)
#1 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(270): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('\r\n.\r\n', Array, Array)
#2 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(333): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('\r\n.\r\n', Array)
#3 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(428): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_streamMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#4 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'info@jeffrey-se...', Array, Array)
#5 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(176): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), 'info@jeffrey-se...', Array, Array)
#6 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(85): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#7 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(385): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#8 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(171): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#9 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(276): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('emails.user.wel...', Array, Object(Closure))
#10 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(130): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->handleQueuedMessage(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\SyncJob), Array)
#11 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/SyncJob.php(44): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->resolveAndFire(Array)
#12 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SyncQueue.php(30): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\SyncJob->fire()
#13 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(187): Illuminate\Queue\SyncQueue->push('mailer@handleQu...', Array, NULL)
#14 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->queue('emails.user.wel...', Array, 'C:32:"SuperClos...')
#15 /home/hubert/hubert/app/Helpers/Helper.php(205): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('queue', Array)
#16 /home/hubert/hubert/app/Http/Controllers/UserapiController.php(667): App\Helpers\Helper::send_email('emails.user.wel...', 'Bienvenue sur J...', 'bruno@email.ch', Object(App\User))
#17 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\UserapiController->register(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('register', Array)
#20 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserapiController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'register')
#21 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#26 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserapiController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'register')
#27 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'register')
#28 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#50 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#55 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#63 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#67 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#68 /home/hubert/hubert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 /home/hubert/hubert/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#70 {main}
```

How can I insure the web service continues to work even if the email was not sent?

---EDIT---

As suggested, I also tried this:

```
public static function send_email($page, $subject, $email, $email_data) {
    if (env('MAIL_USERNAME') && env('MAIL_PASSWORD')) {
        try {
            $site_url = url('/');
            Mail::queue($page, [
                'email_data' => $email_data,
                'site_url' => $site_url,
            ], function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {
                try {
                    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Log::info('email was not sent!!!');
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Helper::get_error_message(123);
        }
        return Helper::get_message(105);
    } else {
        return Helper::get_error_message(123);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have still the same issue.

Comment: change email driver to 'database' or 'redis'

Comment: @ZeroOne, I tried to change the driver in .env file: MAIL_DRIVER=redis
Unfortunately I keep getting a new error "Driver [redis] not supported." (same for database)

Comment: catch the exception and continue execution

Comment: @118218 Redis is a queue driver (and Cache). You can't use it as "Mail_driver".

Comment: What is your queue driver ? You can check in .env. Is it "sync"?